# GirdSearchCV Multiclass-Multioutput

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

Here is my pipeline:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('features', FeatureUnion([

            ('text_pipeline', Pipeline([
                ('count_vectorizer', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)),
                ('tfidf_transformer', TfidfTransformer())
            ])),

            ('starting_verb_transformer', StartingVerbExtractor())
        ])),

        ('classifier',MultiOutputClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced')))
    ])
```

Here is my cv function:

```
parameters = {'classifier__estimator__n_estimators': [10],
               }
cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipeline, param_grid=parameters, cv=2, scoring = "average_precision", verbose=True)
cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: multiclass-multioutput format is not supported
```

But the `pipeline.fit` works well. How can we solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) For instance your data "X_train" and "y_train" is not provided and your error can not be reproduced with your code.

Comment: I know I am late, but for whom it can be helpful the point here is that the scoring parameter `average_precision` is not supported by `MultiOutputClassifier` instances (in turn it is not supported by multioutput-multiclass classification tasks). You can find related references [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score).